# Position fixed not working within overflow hidden parent

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is absolute and have fixed `width` and `height`, I have added overflow auto for scroll bar. It has 3 child in this case and one of them is `position: fixed`, but when I scroll fixed element is also scrolls, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<div class="parent">

<div class="child-1">
    <h1>Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</h1>
</div>

<div class="child-2">
    <h1>Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</h1>
</div>

<div class="child-3">
    <h1>I am fixed.</h1>
</div>
```

here is css

```
.parent {
position: absolute;
width: 320px;
right: 0;
top: 0;
 height: 250px;
 overflow: auto;
bottom: 0;
background: yellow;
z-index: 1000000;
}
.parent .child-3 {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Here is working example of it, https://jsfiddle.net/marslan2037/36833ve6/

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: i have code in this link,  https://jsfiddle.net/marslan2037/36833ve6

Comment: @Saurav Jamwal I added code here...

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: Either I am misunderstanding your post, or your example does what you want it to. The fixed element remains in place while the others scroll. Perhaps our browsers are rendering it differently?

Comment: @pocketg99 i am using chrome

Comment: I just opened it up in Chrome and it seems fine.

Comment: @pocketg99 yes you are right, firefox showing fine, but chrome does not

Comment: but it is not working here in chrome only

Comment: I just opened it in Chrome 59 on OS X and it worked fine.

Comment: my chrome version is, Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: i am not sure why it is not working here

Comment: Put you fixed div outside the parent div

Comment: @Saurav Jamwal thanks, it is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fixed, it's just fixed to the parent element, which you have a scroll on.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sub-parent">
    <div class="child-1">
          <h1>Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</h1>
      </div>

     <div class="child-2">
       <h1>Some Text Some TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome TextSome Text</h1>
     </div>
  </div>
    <div class="child-3">
        <h1>I am fixed.</h1>
    </div>

</div>


.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.sub-parent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 1;
}

.parent .child-3 {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
    color: red;
  z-index: 10
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/baqfqojs/

Hope that works for you.

Comment: thanks your code is working for me in chrome too, but i am not sure why my code is not working in chrome and working fine in firefox and edge,

Comment: Sorry, no idea on that one. That's beyond my pay grade.

Comment: what if i have no choice to put fixed element outside of the parent ?

Comment: If it's outside the parent, the problem becomes easier actually. As long as it's outside of the position: absolute element.

Comment: is there any way if it is not outside of the absolute div?

Comment: No, I think as long as it's inside the absolute div, with the scroll, chrome will position it fixed and scroll it with the other content.